# native app development using cordova and ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

How to keep the process or service always running even after the app is killed by the user, similar like to the stopwatch which will be running even after the app is killed by the user by swiping the in the recent tabs. I know how to keep the service or the process at the background but i don't know how to keep it alive even after it is been .With the help of the [link](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) the running the app in background is possible.

Comment: where are the links?

Comment: no, we can't do it as far as I know. stopwatch/alarm clock are developed along with OS, so they have some additional features.

Comment: but how do the other apps can do that like some other apps which have been downloaded from play store etc